# Django - Query user groups and load iframe source in a custom template based on user group

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, qobject

I usually develop in PHP but I took it upon myself to learn Django so please be patient with me, I have a long way to go... I am working on a project that simply does one thing for now, user can login and when the user is logged in the app will show an Iframe that streams some digital content that is created by another server I have which is stored in this model:

```
class Show(models.Model):
show = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
description = models.TextField()
mfg_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
iframe = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True)
group = models.ForeignKey(
Group,
default='1',
on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
active = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = Active)
def __str__(self):
    return self.show
def show_desc(self):
    return self.description[:50]
```

My views.py currently:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class StreamingView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'stream/stream.html'
```

And my template stream.html:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}[I would like to print "show" from my model here{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
<h2>[I would like to print "show" from my model here]</h2>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="[input "iframe" as the iframe src based on user group, and if user has multiple groups create second iframe to show both at the same time]" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

My question is this:
I am looking to query the group/groups the user belongs to and based on this information create a variable that can input the src of the iframe, it would be best to be able to loop through all the possible "iframe" that the user can see (based on the foreign key to users group) and fill the iframe src on my template with the value stored in my model only if the "show" is active. If the user does not belong to any group or if the show is marked inactive I would like to show an error message something like "You do not have access, please contact the site administrator"

What is the best way to do this? I have been researching Q objects and think I may be able to accomplish this with them?

And lastly is it possible to edit the urls.py to create a urlpattern that takes the name of the group that the user belongs to and uses this name for the url?

Thank you in advance for your help!